How to make a custom type inheriting from UUID work as a pydantic model
in our codebase we are using a custom UUID class. This is a simplified version of it:
class ID(uuid.UUID):
    def __init__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

We cannot inherit from BaseModel and uuid.UUID because pydantic throws an error (due to multiple inheritance not being allowed). Nonetheless, the way it is defined, pydantic throws an error if we use that ID class as part of a pydantic model:
class Model(BaseModel):
    id: ID

This is the error we are getting:
pydantic.errors.PydanticSchemaGenerationError: Unable to generate pydantic-core schema for <class '__main__.ID'>. Set `arbitrary_types_allowed=True` in the model_config to ignore this error or implement `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` on your type to fully support it.

If you got this error by calling handler(<some type>) within `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` then you likely need to call `handler.generate_schema(<some type>)` since we do not call `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` on `<some type>` otherwise to avoid infinite recursion.

For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/u/schema-for-unknown-type

I have read a little bit about how to fix this by trying to implement the function suggested by the error message (__get_pydantic_core_schema__ ). I have tried to fix it by adding the following to the ID class:
    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_json_schema__(cls, core_schema: CoreSchema, handler: GetJsonSchemaHandler):
        return {"type": "UUID"}

    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(cls, source_type: Any, handler: GetCoreSchemaHandler):
        return core_schema.no_info_plain_validator_function(uuid.UUID)

But then I get more errors. Do you know by any chance how to properly setup this?

Pydantic docs on how to handle third-party types: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/types/#handling-third-party-types

You can use RootModel (https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#rootmodel-and-custom-root-types):
import uuid

from pydantic import BaseModel, RootModel


class ID(RootModel):
    root: uuid.UUID


class Model(BaseModel):
    id: ID

m = Model.model_validate({"id": uuid.uuid4()})


